# Rails calculate age in months

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my rails app I have different age groups that students classify in based on how many months their age is. I want a way to be able to calculate when a student is approaching the end of an age group (for example 18 months) so that the user is notified. Is there a way to work with months and date comparisons in Rails to accomplish this? All help is appreciated.

UPDATE:

This an even easier way I figured out how to calculate it `kid.dob.advance(months: 18)` determines the date when the student will reach the end of the age group.

```
<% if kid.dob.advance(months: 17) <= Date.today && kid.dob.advance(months: 18) >= Date.today %>

    // notification

<% end %>
```

This means the user will be notified within 30 days of the student reaching the end of the age group. The numbers can be changed to stored data from a DB as well and it work. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since each age group represents a known number of days after the student's birthdate, you can get what you're looking for by comparing their age (in days) to each particular age group's upper boundary (also in days).

```
age_groups = [6.months, 12.months, 18.months, 24.months, 36.months]
student_age_in_days = (Date.today - student.birthdate)

group_nearing_end = age_groups.detect do |threshold|
  student_age_in_days.between?(threshold - 5.days, threshold)     
end

if group_nearing_end
  # send notification
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my way to do it:

```
def age_in_months(date_of_birth)
  return 0 unless date_of_birth
  Time.zone.today.month + Time.zone.today.year * 12 - date_of_birth.month - date_of_birth.year * 12
end
```

I also saw this implementation:

```
def age_in_months(date_of_birth)
  date_of_birth ? ((Time.zone.today - date_of_birth) / 30.437).to_i : 0
end
```